# alternatives to accessing google reader with oauth?

Tags: oauth, google-reader

I'm really new to this oauth stuff. I want to access a user's google reader liked items feed.

[This blog](http://artofsystems.blogspot.com/2008/11/oauth-not-silver-bullet.html) says that oauth doesn't work (yet) with google reader. [The working way](http://code.google.com/p/pyrfeed/wiki/GoogleReaderAPI) seems to be to get the user's google credentials (email, password) directly, and login directly to google. This also gives me access to the rest of their services.

Is there a better way? I sure hope so, because ClientLogin is captchad. Not to mention I don't want the user to have to trust me with their google credentials.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way ... but you still need the user's Google credentials to access the API.  On the server-side, you can GET a secure token and authentication key ... these are then passed along with GET and POST requests to the Google Reader API to do whatever you want.

[Here's a fairly robust C# tutorial](http://blog.martindoms.com/2010/01/20/using-the-google-reader-api-part-1/) (read the comments to make sure you're doing authentication right).

[Here's an open-source PHP library](http://code.google.com/p/greader-library/) that partially implements the Google Reader API without oAuth.

Answer (score 0):

Authentication to Google Reader with [Oauth](http://groups.google.com/group/fougrapi/browse_thread/thread/4430c9a6dea4d70f/c6e1f942dae407bd?#c6e1f942dae407bd) is now available.